# How to solve the 2-dim linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Since for any periodic equation $A(t)$, the differential equation
$x'(t)=A(t)x(t)$ has the principal matrix solution.

It's trivial for one-dim case, we have $x=\exp(\int_{t_{0}}^{t}a(s)ds)$
where $t_{0}$ is the inital state.

for the equation $x''(t)+\omega^{2}(t)x(t)=0$, suppose $y(t)=x'(t)$,
we have:

$\left(\begin{array}{c}
y'\\
x'
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \omega^{2}\\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
y\\
x
\end{array}\right)=0$. How to solve this for $\omega=\sin(t)+c$ where $c\in\mathbb{R}$ by Floquet's Theorem?